# How do you have a bot post a random gif in an embed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've looked and not really gotten an answer that works. I'm moving from just posting the attachment(no link) to trying to put it in an embed. I used discord.js.org to help me come up with the code below, however when I use the command it just ends up as a completely blank embed that's just a small square. Not even big enough where the gif would just not be loading. This square is tiny. I'm not sure why it's doing this.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const prefix = require('../config.json');
const angryGif = require('../AngryWolves.json');
const colors = require('../colors.json');

module.exports = {
    name: "angry",
    description: "Posts a random GIF of an angry wolf.",
    usage: `${prefix}angry`,
    execute(message, args) {
        const gif = new Discord.MessageAttachment(angryGif[Math.floor(Math.random() * angryGif.length)]);
        
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(colors.blue)
        .setImage(String[angryGif[gif]])

        message.channel.send(embed);
    },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what `angryGifs` is, is it an array of string urls? list of objects?

Assuming `angryGifs` is a list of string urls to gifs:

First:

```js
const gif = new Discord.MessageAttachment(angryGif[Math.floor(Math.random() * angryGif.length)])
```

This would make a message attachment of the gif, which wouldn't be inside of the embed

so instead do:

```js
const gif = angryGif[Math.floor(Math.random() * angryGif.length)];
```

Second: `.setImage(String[angryGif[gif]])`

Here you are getting a property from string which the property name would be `angryGif[gif]`, `angryGif[gif]` would result in undefined so essentialy:

```js
String[undefined]
```

Your gif should already be a string, so all you need is:

```js
embed.setImage(gif);
```

Also if your links are referring to some imgur link or a giphy link, it's possible they aren't linking to the actual gif source.

For example: https://media.giphy.com/media/l396KvvE78gsGhr8c/giphy.gif

When you visit this page it shows the gif along side with some other text like "see more dog gifs", that indicates it's not the direct source, to get the direct source you would right click the gif and press copy url

which would result in this link: https://i.giphy.com/media/l396KvvE78gsGhr8c/giphy.webp

Which is a direct source.

Comment: This is a fantastic amount of information. Thank you for clarifying everything. I had tried many times to get to a point where I wasn't receiving errors and this is definitely the solution. Works perfectly now!